# BUG: Scheduling while atomic .... using sysfs_notify()

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, scheduling

I have a kernel module that uses hrtimers to notify userspace when the timer has fired. I understand I can just use userspace timers, but it is emulating a driver that will actually talk to hardware in the future. Every once in a while I get a `BUG: Scheduling while atomic`. After doing some research I am assuming that the `hrtimer.function` that I register as a callback, is being called from an interrupt routine by the kernel internals (making my callback function in an "Atomic Context"). Then when I call `sysfs_notify()` within the callback, I get the kernel bug, because sysfs_notify() acquires a mutex.

1) Is this a correct assumption?

If this is correct, I have seen that there is a function called `sys_notify_dirent()` that I can use to notify userspace from an atomic context. But according to this source:

http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Kernel/2009-10/msg07510.html

It can only be called from a "process" context, and not an interrupt context (due to the spinlock).

2) Could someone explain the difference between process, interrupt, and atomic context?

3) If this cannot be used in an interrupt context, what is an alternative to notifying userspace in this context?

Comment: Did you read chapter 7 of LDD3?

Comment: Months ago. I could probably use a refresher, but I don't remember it mentioning anything about sys_notify_dirent()

Comment: It mentions deferred work.

Comment: I would not like to defer work. I am trying to pass an interrupt to userspace through a sysfs_notify. But the interrupt is clearly of Interrupt/Atomic context. The Hrtimer is just providing me with the same timing that the hardware will be giving me interrupts for. I would like userspace to wake up as soon as possible after the interrupt (i.e. not deferred)

Comment: Hardware drivers work the same way.  The top-half interrupt handler is atomic, and needs to complete quickly, with no chance of blocking.  Any interaction with userspace is inappropriate here.  The bottom-half handler is deferred, and does the bulk of the work related to the interrupt.  If your userspace code is concerned about these small scheduling delays, then your design is wrong.

Comment: So.. Back to my question, can I use sysfs_notify_dirent(), from an atomic context?

Comment: check out Linux/drivers/gpio/gpiolib-sysfs.c and look at the function `static irqreturn_t gpio_sysfs_irq(int irq, void *priv)` It directly calls `sysfs_notify_dirent()` does that mean that the GPIO driver's design is wrong?

Comment: No, it means this function uses deferred work internally, as it should, and that userspace GPIO code needs to be tolerant of those potential scheduling delays.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, `sysfs_notify()` cannot be called from atomic context.  And yes, `sysfs_notify_dirent()` appears to be safe to call from atomic context.  The source you cite is a bug report that notices in an old kernel version that statement wasn't actually true, along with a patch to fix it.  It now appears to be safe to call.

Follow the source code in gpiolib_sysfs.c, and you'll notice that `sysfs_notify_dirent()` eventually calls `schedule_work()`, which defers the actual call to `sysfs_notify()`, which is exactly what the comments to your question are advising you to do.  It's just wrapped inside the convenience function.

Comment: Thank your for the explanation, that clears things up greatly.